# log the data from an array to console.log in Angular Typescript

Tags: html, json, angular, console.log

.html file

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let info of (this.info || [])">    
<h5 class="card-title" (click)="getInfo()">{{info.paragraph1}}</h5>
</div>
```

.ts file

```
getInfo () {

*****console.log(_____????)*****

this.apiService.getInfo()
.subscribe( (data : any) => {
    this.Info = data;
    console.log(this.Info);
});
```

}

There will be several different `{{info.paragraph1}}` 's displayed on the site. When a user clicks on a specific `paragraph1`, I want that `paragraph1` to be logged on the console so i can access it specifically with my server side code and use it in SQL queries.

Does anyone know how i can log specifically the user's selected `{{info.paragraph1}}` with console.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a parameter to your `getInfo()` function where you transfer the paragraph content from the "clicked" element to your function (and api server).

```
<h5 class="card-title" (click)="getInfo(info.paragraph1)">{{info.paragraph1}}</h5>
```

Modify the `getInfo` function to allow for a parameter:

```
getInfo (paragraph) {
  console.log(paragraph);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the parameter to your method, which you want to console.log

```
getInfo (paragraph) {
  console.log(paragraph);
}
```

and send it like this

```
<h5 class="card-title" (click)="getInfo(info.paragraph1)">{{info.paragraph1}}</h5>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.